# How to get AngularJS to show data on other devices on local network

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mobile

I am quite new to developing and I got a issue that I can't find an solution for yet. At the moment I have a functionality that lets the user remove and add items and shows these items in a list.

I have tested this on different browers (Chrome, Edge, Internet Explorer) on non-mobile devices  and ***it all works fine*** and shows me the list.

But when I test this on my mobile devices (iPad3, Nokia Lumia 820) it does show the website, but it seems that it is not loading the data.

**Question:** What do I need to do to get my data displayed on my mobile devices too and thus get my app working.

**Output on non-mobile devices:**
[image]

**Output on mobile devices:**
[image]

Thanks in advance for the suggestions!!

Comment: You'll have to provide some code so we can answer that question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the issue. I was running my JSON API on my local machine, but in the factory I had linked to localhost instead of the IP-address of my machine in the network.

So instead of defining my resource as `$resource("http://localhost:8001/items/:itemId", {itemId: "@itemId"}, {})` I now linked to the host:

```
var url = "http://" + $location.host() + ":8001/items/:itemId";
var resource = $resource(url, {itemId: "@itemId"}, {});
```